# Running .ipa apps on windows

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, emulation, ipa

I am trying to run an ipa app on my windows computer. If you are wondering why it is an app that is no longer on ios, and I don't have an ios or apple device anymore. I have tried emulating mac on virtualbox but it has always flopped. Is this even possible to do and if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: First off, if this is an IPA from the appstore it is compiled for an ARM processor. So you might get lucky on one of the new ARM(Apple Silicon) Macs.
For windows you will need to emulate a iPhone, which I do not think that is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is almost impossible to run a .ipa on windows, as there are no true iOS emulators for Windows. I say almost because some programs (e.g. BlackThunder) emulate MacOS, which then runs apps recompiled for the iOS SDK, and through this method it is possible to play certain apps. However, none of these programs actually emulate iOS itself.